# Can I loop through my controls and retrieve the name of their assigned properties?

Tags: vb.net, properties, controls

I have a list of checkboxes and I need to get the property name if the check box - or is there a more efficient way of doing this? The code below ensure that only two checkboxes can only be clicked on at a time and I need to get the name of the two checkboxes.

Current code:

```
Private Sub cb_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chckJan.
   CheckedChanged,
   chckFeb.CheckedChanged,
   chckMar.CheckedChanged,
   chckApr.CheckedChanged,
   chckMay.CheckedChanged,
    chckJun.CheckedChanged,
   chckJul.CheckedChanged,
    chckAug.CheckedChanged,
chckOct.CheckedChanged,
  chckNov.CheckedChanged,
   chckDec.CheckedChanged


    'get all checkboxes
    Dim Months = Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)().ToArray()
    'Get the number of checked CheckBoxes.
    Dim checkedBoxCount = Months.Count(Function(cb) cb.Checked)
    'Unchecked CheckBoxes should be enabled if and only if the number of checked CheckBoxes is less than the maximum number allowed.
    Dim enableUncheckedBoxes = checkedBoxCount < 2
    'Get the unchecked CheckBoxes.
    Dim uncheckedBoxes = Months.Where(Function(cb) Not cb.Checked)
    'Enable or disable the unchecked CheckBoxes as appropriate.
    For Each uncheckedBox In uncheckedBoxes
        uncheckedBox.Enabled = enableUncheckedBoxes
    Next

    Dim CheckBoxArray As CheckBox() = {chckJan, chckFeb, chckMar, chckApr, chckMay, chckJun, chckJul, chckAug, chckSep, chckOct, chckNov, chckDec}

    For Each CheckBox In CheckBoxArray
        If CheckBox.Checked = True Then

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You have already extracted a list of checkbox unchecked, extracting a list of checkbox checked should be a piece of cake. By the way, handler misses the chckSep

Comment: a pair of combo boxes is more appropriate for the use case you describe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to get the name of the two checkboxes

You've already got a loop; use it:

```
For Each CheckBox In CheckBoxArray
    If CheckBox.Checked = True Then
        Debug.Print(CheckBox.Name)
    End If
Next
```